# PHP template multiple variable replace with seperator

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace multiple variables in a template with 2 attributes or sometimes only 1.

At the moment if there is no 2nd attribute the last character is being captured by the 2nd regex group.

```
$content = 'Lorem ipsum {monthly_price} and {yearly_price|site-network} Lorem ipsum'; 
function get_replacement($matches) {
    $attr = $matches[1]; // Index 1 is the first capture group
    $deal = $matches[2];
    return $attr;
}
$content = preg_replace_callback('/{([a-z_]+)\|?([a-z-]+)}/', 'get_replacement', $content);
echo $content;
```

Output:
`Lorem ipsum monthly_pric and yearly_price Lorem ipsum`

Comment: Change your regex to `/{([a-z_]+)(?:\|([a-z-]+))?}/`. The result that you seek is unclear otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`$deal = $matches[2];` is a wasted line of code because you aren't doing anything with the assigned variable.

`$attr = $matches[1];` loses its last character because the literal pipe is optional, but the part of the pattern that follows it requires at least one qualifying character before the closing curly brace.

To fix your pattern and make your the portion starting with the pipe optional, you need to create an optional non-capturing group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bTK4U))

```
$content = 'Lorem ipsum {monthly_price} and {yearly_price|site-network} Lorem ipsum'; 
function get_replacement($matches) {
    var_export($matches);
    echo "\n---\n";
    return "<< {$matches[1]}" . (isset($matches[2]) ? " & {$matches[2]}" : '') . " >>";
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/{([a-z_]+)(?:\|?([a-z-]+))?}/', 'get_replacement', $content);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '{monthly_price}',
  1 => 'monthly_price',
)
---
array (
  0 => '{yearly_price|site-network}',
  1 => 'yearly_price',
  2 => 'site-network',
)
---
Lorem ipsum << monthly_price >> and << yearly_price & site-network >> Lorem ipsum
```